# Select all results from database table where condition is met, limit results to 6 - and if results less than 6 show advert/div also

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table in my database called users. At the moment I have 5 users in my table users.

I am trying to list up to 6 users from my table using the below code:

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 'active' AND usertype = 'advertiser' LIMIT 6";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // First parameter is just return of "mysqli_connect()" function
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo "<div id='prime'>" .$row['username']. "</div>"; // I just did not use "htmlspecialchars()" function. 

    } ?>
```

My query is only fetching 5 results, because that's all there is in the table like so:

```
User1.  User2.   User3.   User4.   User5.
```

If there are not at least 6 users in the table then i still want 6 items to show, the alternative being a kind of advertisement div - like so:

```
User 1.  User 2.   User 3.   User 4.   User 5.  Advertise Here 6.
```

How can I amend/improve my code to achieve the above?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for` loop:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 'active' AND usertype = 'advertiser' LIMIT 6";
$result = $conn->query($sql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

for ($key = 0; $key < 6; $key++) {
    if (isset($result[$key])) {
        echo "<div id='prime'>" .htmlspecialchars($result[$key]['username']). "</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div id='prime'>Advertise here</div>";
    }
}
```

or you can also use `while` loop.

```
$key = 0;
while ($key != 6) {
    if (isset($result[$key])) {
        echo "<div id='prime'>" .htmlspecialchars($result[$key]['username']). "</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div id='prime'>Advertise here</div>";
    }
    $key++;
}
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless